# Facebook Like Button Callback JavaScript 2018

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an issue with the existing Facebook Callback JavaScript codes that i used.

Every time i go to the page (the page where my Facebook button is) and press the "Like" button from Facebook, i get a pop-up dialog that gives me the option to Like the page or cancel/close the pop-up.

[image]

But once i press "Like", the callbacks does not work. The callback will only work if i click on "Like"(or "Dislike") the second time and onward.

This is the code i am using.

```
        <script>
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId            : 'MY_APPID',
                    autoLogAppEvents : true,
                    xfbml            : true,
                    version          : 'v2.12'
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (response) {
                    console.log('Liked: ' + response);
                });
                FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function (response) {
                    console.log('DisLiked: ' + response)
                });
            };
            (function(d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                js = d.createElement(s); 
                js.id = id;
                js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=MY_APPID&autoLogAppEvents=1';
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>
        <div id="fb-root"></div><div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MyURL" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

I checked similar questions here in StackOverflow, but it seems like most if not all is out dated. Hope anyone can help me with this.

Comment: Could it be because of cookies? Maybe the first time you click, it tries to set a cookie and quit. The second time it finds the cookie and fires? I remember people used to put inside FB.init, cookie:true as well. Isn't it this the case still?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me. what im suspecting is the pop-up that shows up when you first click the "Like" button every time you load/refresh the page.

Comment: Doesn't that pop up because it doesn't find a certain cookie??

Comment: afaik the like callbacks are deprecated anyway, what for do you want to use them?

Comment: a client wants me to have a function where visitors/users of the website needs to press the Like button to get a specific amount of points.

Comment: Then please tell your client that what they are asking for is absolutely not allowed. https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5: _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ See also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: Thanks @CBroe .. You should add it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a client wants me to have a function where visitors/users of the website needs to press the Like button to get a specific amount of points.

Then please tell your client that what they are asking for is absolutely not allowed.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, point 4.4:

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.

See also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.4 for more examples of what exactly is and isn’t allowed.